# How can I play a sound in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, audio

How can I play a sound in WinForms with C#?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For playing sound simply, with no interaction you can use System.Media.SoundPlayer:

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
player.SoundLocation = "soundFile.wav";
player.Play();
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get "the format of the URI cannot be determined". Seems it needs a full path, not just a relative path.

Answer (score 9):

NAudio is a great library to reproduce sound, you can find it here:
http://naudio.codeplex.com/

And the tutorial is here:
http://opensebj.blogspot.com/2009/02/introduction-to-using-naudio.html