# Playing MP3 file using C#

Tags: c#, audio

I'm looking for a way for playing an MP3 file without any 3rd side playing it(Media Player, etc) Is there any way for doing it?
 Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playing sounds in Winforms using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304223/playing-sounds-in-winforms-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have written an open source library called [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com) that can do this:

```
private IWavePlayer waveOut;
private Mp3FileReader mp3FileReader;

private void PlayMp3()
{
    this.waveOut = new WaveOut(); // or new WaveOutEvent() if you are not using WinForms/WPF
    this.mp3FileReader = new Mp3FileReader("myfile.mp3");
    this.waveOut.Init(mp3FileReader);
    this.waveOut.Play();
    this.waveOut.PlaybackStopped += OnPlaybackStopped;
}

private void OnPlaybackStopped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.waveOut.Dispose();
    this.mp3FileReader.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess that was what I am looking for, the OnPlaybackStopped event is being fired when the song reaches its end?

Comment: @idish, NAudio is nicely documented, and for your questions, simply play with it and you will see the answers out.

Comment: I am using NAudio to play mp3 files, it was playing fine but few moments before it stopped playing songs and there isn't any error being thrown. Here is my code https://pastebin.com/m5NLHfdy

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to avoid 3rd party libraries. If you're coding in c# you're probably developing for windows, which normally has winmm.dll. So you can import and use `mciSendString` [like in this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17279/Using-mciSendString-to-play-media-files).

However, if you convert the MP3 data to raw data, you can play it using the .NET [SoundPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx) class.