# How to get a wav file to play in the background when a form is opened?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, audio

I want a wav file to play in the background of a form when it is opened. How do I do this?

Comment: Use Form Load Event, and in the event method you might try to play your Wav File.

Comment: Look at those duplicate questions and see if their answers are useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025626/playing-a-mp3-file-in-a-winform-application, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645386/playing-mp3-file-using-c-sharp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304223/playing-sounds-in-winforms-using-c-sharp

Comment: None of them questions are duplicate to mine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code to the event when you want to play the file:

```
     var player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
     player.SoundLocation = @"D:\.....\some file.wav";
     player.Load();
     player.Play();
```

Comment: Yep already had that code, I just had it in the wrong place of the code, . Thanks