# how to add a warning sound in a winforms when an listview is update

Tags: winforms

I am creating a winforms application when that will check if what background serives are gone into to list views controls that i have created One Amber and Red to see which are running and which are not. what I would like to do is when the services goes into the red list view it makes how can i achieve this

Comment: Your question is incredibly unclear, I'm afraid (what is [One Amber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Amber)? what is [Red](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red:_The_Dark_Side)?). Maybe you should add code samples and/or pictures to illustrate your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Playing sounds in Winforms using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304223/playing-sounds-in-winforms-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks guys i am really new to Stack-overflow so sorry if my questions are bad  what i meant is i am doing a windows service that is creating like  traffic light system/Heartbeat system that where i am pulling a list of company services from a database. What I have done it to create 2 list view controls that the services go into. The first list view is amber like a warning light the second list view is red where the sound would play i just wanted to know where to begin