# How can I play a sound in a thread?

Tags: c#, winforms, console, beep

I want to play a beep for 1 second in thread. I'm not familiar with threads and maybe there is another easy way without using threads. I used console.beep(), but unfortunately it freeze's the form for a second.

```
while(true)
{
   do some jobs;
   console.beep();
}
```

The Winform app freeze on the console.beep(); for one second. I need to pass the line and simultaneously beep for one second.

Comment: Please show us some code so we can help you identify what is wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304223/how-can-i-play-a-sound-in-winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
using System.Media;


    SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
```

And Play() doesn't block so you don't need a Thread. 
It plays whatever is configured in the User's sytem sound settings.

But if you need to know when the sound has finished this is not what you want.

[How to: Play a Beep from a Windows Form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-play-a-beep-from-a-windows-form)